# How to do a Level 0 DFD for a game?

Tags: software-design, dataflow-diagram

I am creating a data flow diagram for a game that I am creating and I was thinking what a level 0 dfd would look like. So far I have come to the conclusion that the input would be mouse clicks and keyboard input. The process would be the game. But I don't know what the output would be seeing as a game is continuous until it is over and then there is no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to make a game except you don't know what to make...

Well, this is the best I can do for you https://obviam.net/posts/2010/05.basic-game-loop/ it'll help you understand and organize your game loop.

Don't worry it says android in it, the basic concept is the same and this is a link i had on my hand...